# AHK script cicle left click

Tags: autohotkey

I made a script for a cyclic click with the left mouse button clamped, but things are much more complicated with the joystick, I still could not figure out how to rewrite my script so that it would do cyclic RT(RightTrigger) clicks with RT clamped. Please help me!

```
del:= 100 ; ms
 
~LButton::
  Loop
  {
    if not GetKeyState("LButton", "P")      
      break
    MouseClick, Left
    Sleep, %del%
  }
return
```

I tried to do this using the XInput library since I have an XBox joystick, but it didn't work out :(Since RT is a trigger, you need to get the value from the degree of pressure on the button, and there are values from 0 to 257, and I couldn't make the script so that when RT was clamped, it produced mini presses with a delay of ms.